Constructing a gapped family of Hamiltonians in the trivial paramagnet
Consider the trivial paramagnet, which has the Hamiltonian $$H = - \sum_i \sigma^x_i$$ Now let's say I have two different Hamiltonians $$H_0 = H + 2\sigma^x_{i_0} \qquad H_1 = H + 2\sigma^x_{i_1}$$ These Hamiltonians have (unique) ground states ${\psi_0}, {\psi_1}$ respectively, where ${\psi_{a}}$ is the state in the -1 eigenbasis of $\sigma^x_{i_a}$ and in the +1 eigenbasis of $\sigma^x_{i}$ with $i \neq i_a$. I wanted to construct a gapped family of Hamiltonians $H(s)$ such that the GS of $H(0)$ is ${\psi_0}$ and similarly for $H(1)$.
I suspect that if I define the vector $${\xi (s)} = s {\psi_1} + (1-s) {\psi_0}$$ then the Hamiltonian $$H(s) = H - 2|{\xi(s)}\rangle \langle {\xi(s)}|$$ is the family I want. How can I see that this family is indeed gapped or not?
My reasoning was that the Hamiltonian family $H(s)$ projects to a particular pure state ${\xi}$ as the (unique?) ground state, and has the required ground states at $s= 0,1$.
EDIT:
For some context, this question is supposed to be a toy example for an equivalent question about the Toric Code in the infinite volume. Suppose $H^{TC} = - \sum_v A_v - \sum_f B_f$, and consider $H_0 = H^{TC} + 2 A_{v_0}$ and similarly define $H_1$. Let $\psi_0/ \psi_1$ be the unique FF GS of $H_0/ H_1$. Then I want to show that there indeed exists a gapped family of Hamiltonians that are deformations of the Toric Code Hamiltonian (So Hamiltonians of the form $H(s) = H^{TC} + \Phi(s)$ where $\Phi(s)$ is a bounded term. Projections are fine as they preserve the length of vectors.) that transports a charge from $v_0$ to $v_1$.

Do you want your family of Hamiltonians to be local? If so I don’t think your projector is a local operator.

Since H is noninteracting you can just add a local transverse field sigma^y to sites i0, i1, and use that to rotate them from -1 to +1  (or vice versa). This will definitely be gapped the whole way.

A different way that might generalize better is to tune via a strong Heisenberg AFM coupling  (you do need off-diagonal components), so that you go from excitation at 0 --> excitation delocalized between 0,1  (spin singlet) --> excitation at 1.

For the toric code, if $v_0$ and $v_1$ are neighboring sites, denote by $e$ the edge connecting them, then $Z_e H_0 Z_e=H_1$ (assuming your $A_v$ is a product of $X$'s). Then we can define $H(s)=e^{is\frac{\pi}{2} Z_e}H_0 e^{-is \frac{\pi}{2}Z_e}$. When $s=0$, $H(0)=H_0$ and $H(1)=H_1$, and it's just unitary conjugation, so must be gapped everywhere. Then you can do a bunch of these to go from any site to any other site.

Let us label the states using the eigenstates of the paul-X operator $|\pm\rangle$. The ground states of $H_0$ and $H_1$ are, respectively $|-++++\ldots\rangle$ and $|+-+++\ldots\rangle$. The state you add is $|\xi(s)\rangle = (s|+-\rangle+(1-s)|-+\rangle) |+++\ldots\rangle$. As mentioned by others, your projector, $|\xi(s)\rangle \langle \xi(s) | = (s|+-\rangle+(1-s)|-+\rangle) (s\langle+-|+(1-s)\langle-+\rangle|) |+++\ldots \rangle \langle +++\ldots|$ is non-local. This is because of the factors $|+++\ldots \rangle \langle +++\ldots|$ acting on sites 3,4,... You can instead use the following projector that only operates on sites 1 and 2: $P(s)=(s|+-\rangle+(1-s)|-+\rangle) (s\langle+-|+(1-s)\langle-+\rangle|) \otimes 1 \otimes 1 \ldots$ where the identity operators act on sites 3,4, and so on. The Hamiltonian interpolating between the two ground states is $H(s) = -P(s) - \sum_{j>3} \sigma^x_j$ which has ground state $|\xi(s)\rangle |+++\ldots \rangle$. This does not close a gap because the operator acting on the first two terms form a rank-1 projector for every value of $s \in [0,1]$.
An alternative route, as mentioned by Meng is to consider a unitary transformation $U(s) = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2} (s\sigma^z_2 + (1-s) \sigma^z_1) }$. You can check that $H(s) = U(s) H_0 U(s)^\dagger$ gives the interpolation you are looking for. There is no gap cloure since unitary transformations do not change the spectrum.
